# Android AVD Emulator Runaway CPU. Fix? Anyone else having the same issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

**Android Studio 1.2.1.1** on an `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit` both fully update.

When run one `Emulator` the `CPU` runs real hard, about `4x` times as before an upgrade a couple of weeks ago. Seems like each `Emulator` is using more `RAM` than before as well. Can only run at most 3 `Emulator`  before the computer becomes overloaded and unresponsive, before could run at least 8.

I checked to make sure all the required `Linux` libraries are on the machine.

Filed a bug on Android Studio as:

> [Issue 173578](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=173578&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=173578):    Race condition when running AVD Emulator since updating Android SDK Tools, revision 24.2

Just started UI tuning (Again) and this problem is killing me time wise since I can not open many emulators to check the UI.

Anyone else having the same or similar problem? If so star the bug report.

Anyone know of a fix?